# Copy and Paste VBA - Skip Blanks, No header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move data from one workbook to another for mapping. I don't need the header and want to skip blanks.

I can get it to skip blanks but then it copies the columns beside it. 
I can also get it to copy and paste only the column but it doesn't skip the blanks. So I just need a way for it to do column A only, no header, and keep it blank on the new sheet.

I've tried Skip blanks in the Paste special and it doesn't work.

```
Sub NewCopyandPaste()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim weTarget As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range

    Set wsSource = Workbooks("Book1.csv").Worksheets("Book1")
    Set weTarget = Workbooks("Book2.csv").Worksheets("Book2")

    With wsSource
        Set y = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        y.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    End With

    weTarget.Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this (Set y = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))) will give you range from A2 to first blank in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
Set y = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

sets `y` to the range from `A2` down to the cell above *first* blank cell <sup>Note 1</sup>

hange that to use `End(XlUp)` from the bottom of the sheet

```
Set y = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

<sub>Note 1.  stritcly speaking, what is copied will depend on if cell `A3` is blank.</sub>

Comment: if many blank cell, this will stop in first blank cell, I think, may be you must loop several times

Comment: @user11982798 if you test it you will find it copies all non-blanl calles to a contiguous range

Comment: So you take it from bottom? OK I understand

Comment: Is there any way I can keep the blank when transferring? @chrisneilsen

Comment: @crystal if you don't want to skip the blanks don't use `SpecialCells` , ie just `y.Copy`

Comment: @chrisneilsen why does it always start at A2 even when I change the range to C2

Comment: @Crystal _What_ did you change to `C2`?  Maybe you want `Set y = .Range(.Range("C2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))`  (note the `3`)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I see thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Crystal happy to help.  Since you are new here, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: crystal, this to get the last row and column without must refer to A2: .Application.ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell) as cell or .Cells..ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell), also as cell, with this cell you can get your last row and last column.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might be with your range creation.  Try:

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim weTarget As Worksheet
Dim y As Range

Set wsSource = Workbooks("Book1.csv").Worksheets("Book1")
Set weTarget = Workbooks("Book2.csv").Worksheets("Book2")

With wsSource
  Set y = Range("A2").End(xlDown)
    y.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
End With

weTarget.Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: I appreciate you with your contribution, but I think Set y = Range("A2").End(xlDown) will stop before the last blank cell in column A. Here we are same, to learn more for the better.

Comment: this to find the last row: ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row